# How to make my calendar appear on my home page in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am new to Drupal and am using the default Bartik theme to learn the environment.  I've been able to install the Calendar module and have it appear on all the pages I created.  These pages are accessible from the menu Tabs I have created across the top of my page header.  However, whenever I click on the Home Tab the sidebar calendar is removed.  How can I get my sidebar calendar to appear on my HOME page just like it does for my other pages that I access through the Menu Tabs?

Answer (score 0):

Check your Block settings (www.yoursite.com/admin/structure/block) there should be calendar block in sidebar. Check that the block is marked to be visible in all pages (from block settings).

Comment: Thank you. I checked Structure --> Blocks.  For the "Sidebar First" block I went to configure the "View: Calendar".  For Visibility Settings: Pages, I have selected "Show block on specific pages: All pages except those listed". In the listed pages I DO NOT have the HOME page mentioned. And yet the calendar does not appear on the Home page. I have other pages that I created listed in that group and rightfully so, the calendar does not appear on those pages.  On the other pages that I created and DID NOT list in that group, the calendar rightfully appears as well.

Comment: So that functionality seems to be working fine.  But on the Home page the calendar does not appear even though the HOME page is not one of those pages listed as not having the Calendar. (I hope that's not too confusing)

Answer (score 0):

OK here's the solution: Go to STRUCTURE --> BLOCKS and click on the "configure" link for the Calendar View in the block section SIDEBAR FIRST. Then click on the Content Types TAB, and UNCHECK all the content types.  I thought by checking them all it would make the calendar visibal everywhere, but apparently that applied a restriction to the Home page. By Unchecking all the boxes, the view is now visible on the Home page.